# New GMSMapView not working, but old GMSMapView loading properly

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

When I create a new GMSMapView it does not load. I have other GMSMapViews in my project that do load properly. I am using the storyboard editor to assign the custom subclass of GMSMapView to a UIView. Why are the new ones not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue by looking at the source code for my storyboard file.

My old GMSMapViews looked like this:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" 
      id="hbm-BT-3Ow" customClass="GMSMapView">
```

My new ones looked like this:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" 
      id="alb-9Z-Vu8" customClass="GMSMapView" 
      customModule="{My Project Name}" customModuleProvider="target">
```

When I set the custom class to GMSMapView for a new UIView, the associated Module was 'my project' instead of 'none' as it was previously.

[image]

The issue was that I created a custom extension for GMSMapView in my project.

```
extension GMSMapView {

    var visibleBounds: GMSCoordinateBounds {
        return GMSCoordinateBounds(region: self.projection.visibleRegion())
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

Changing `extension GMSMapView` to `extension GoogleMaps.GMSMapView` fixed my problem.